# how get width and height of Image control

Tags: asp.net, image, image-resizing

I want to change the size of my image in asp.net proportionally, the problem is that I can't get the actual size of the image which is loaded from database. here is the code:

```
imgAvatar.ImageUrl = "~/Modules/FileViewer.ashx?id=" + o.EventID;                      
        double r = imgAvatar.Width.Value / 300.00;
        imgAvatar.Width = new Unit(300, UnitType.Pixel);
        imgAvatar.Height = new Unit(imgAvatar.Height.Value / r, UnitType.Pixel);
```

but the `imgAvatar.Width.Value` is always 0.0. 
what would you suggest to me?

Comment: You should do resizing in FileViewer.ashx, as far I can see that handler serves image, so why not resize it there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not set width and height.** The rendered IMG tag will be sized to the size of downloaded image.

However, if the image is too large you might have a problem. In that case, use CSS to set max:

```
max-width: 300px;
max-height: 300px;
```

---

I might have misunderstand the question, considering my answer above. Anyways, **the way I see that done would be similar to this:**

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(this.Server.MapUrl("~/image path here"));

// sorry if the above line doesn't compile; writing from memory, use intellisense to find these classes/methods

// image.Width and image.Height will work here
```

Comment: if I set max width and max-height will it restrict the size proportionally?     The second option is not valid, because I can't sepcify the url of my image in MapUrl, it will cause  "Ilegal character exception" cause my image url contains "?"

Comment: #1 yes, the size will be proportional; it will be less than or equal to whatever size you set as max. #2, if you want to do that, strip out extra characters from path: `int idx = pathString.IndexOf('?')`, then `if(idx > 0) pathString.Substring(0, idx)`;

Answer (score 0):

Takes the size of the image with Bitmap and calls the below function to resize

```
Bitmap myBitmap;
string fileName = "foreverAlone.jpg";
myBitmap = new Bitmap(fileName);

Size newSize = NewImageSize(myBitmap.Height, myBitmap.Width, 100);//myBitMap.Height and myBitMap.Width is how you take the original size
```

Check BitMap class here [Bitmap Class - MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx)

This code returns new size of the image, and image quality remains the same -no reduce-, `FormatSize` parameter decides the new size.

```
 public Size NewImageSize(int OriginalHeight, int OriginalWidth, double FormatSize)
        {
            Size NewSize;
            double tempval;

            if (OriginalHeight > FormatSize && OriginalWidth > FormatSize)
            {
                if (OriginalHeight > OriginalWidth)
                    tempval = FormatSize / Convert.ToDouble(OriginalHeight);
                else
                    tempval = FormatSize / Convert.ToDouble(OriginalWidth);

                NewSize = new Size(Convert.ToInt32(tempval * OriginalWidth), Convert.ToInt32(tempval * OriginalHeight));
            }
            else
                NewSize = new Size(OriginalWidth, OriginalHeight); 

            return NewSize;
        }
```

Comment: @Andron sorry no need to yell with punctuation.Here I edit my post with that.

Comment: @RoboLover don't offend I just wanted to stress it.

Comment: Let's see what I can do, as mentioned in another answer there is a problem initiating Bitmap, because I have a handler that gives me image, and for example I can't use MapUrl

Comment: @Andron would `Server.MapPath` help about that?I am not sure if same problem occurs.

Comment: No Server.MapPath will not work in such situation, it will cause "Ilegal character exception"